# Rails Redirect fails after delete. (Delete is successful but display of remaining records does not happen)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, activerecord, actionpack

When a user calls the users_path view, all users are rendered correctly in the display.

However I also redirect to index after a delete. The console indicates a 200 Ok but then the index is not rendered.

Trying to step through some of the rails code, it looks like in the case of after the delete, rails does an implicit render. It doesn't do this in the first case of calling the index view.

views/users/index.rb

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
<tr class = '<%=cycle('dataeven', 'dataodd')%>' > 
<td class = '<%=cell_class%>'><%= user.username %></td>
<td <class = '<%=cell_class%>'><%= user.email %></td>
<td class = '<%=cell_class%>'><%= user.actual_name %></td>
<td class = '<%=link_cell_class%>'><%= tlink_to 'edit_permissions', permissions_path(user) %></td>
<td class = '<%=link_cell_class%>'><%= tlink_to 'reset_password', edit_password_path(user) %></td>
<td class = '<%=link_cell_class%>'><%= unlock_link(user) %></td>
<td class = '<%=link_cell_class%>'><%= tlink_to("destroy", destroy_user_path(user), {:navigate=>false, :method=>'delete', :remote=>true, :data=>{:confirm=>tmessage( 'delete.are_you_sure', $W, {:model=>user.username}) }})%></td>
</tr>
<%end%>
</table>
<%= twill_paginate %>
<br>

<%= link_to t('headings.new.heading', :model=> t($ARM + 'user', :count=>1)), new_user_path %> | <%= tlink_to "new_invitation", new_user_invitation_path%></li>
```

users_controller.rb

```
def index
  @users = User.paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 15
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html 
    format.xml  { render :xml => @translation_languages }
  end
end
```

.....
users_controller.rb
...

```
def destroy    
  @user.destroy
  tflash('delete', :success, {:model=>@@model, :count=>1})
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to(users_url) }
    format.xml  { head :ok }
  end
end
```

Has any one any idea what may cause the redirect to silent stop

Comment: Take a look at the logs and see if you can see what the format of the request is.  If it's not html, it won't hit the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Two questions which may help lead you to a solution:

1. What are the contents of the tflash method? (Does it work if you comment it out?)
2. Why does your destroy action respond to xml?

Comment: The tflash is just a translated wrapper for the flash. I'll look into it and see if there is a problem there. No reason for the xml. I'll remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I see the link is remote - this will be a js format.

Do this:

Create a destroy.js.erb file and put it in the same directory with index.
You can do javascript in there, for example - remove the element

in views/users/destroy.js.erb

```
$("##{dom_id(user)}").remove()
```

In the view, add this to the user row:

```
<tr class = '<%=cycle('dataeven', 'dataodd')%> <%= dom_id(user) %>' >
```

EDIT

You can also just remove the remote: true.  Should have mentioned that.

Comment: This would be a fudge. All the other controllers work for delete without such a problem. There is something wrong with the destroy action in this controller. The record is removed from the db, the view is read and filled with the correct data. A 200 code is sent, but the screen never paints.

Comment: If you look in the logs, it it trying to render destroy.js (no template found)?  Did you mean to have remote true in there?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions guys.

The solution turned out to be painfully obvious: All the other deletes in this application had involved a full refresh of the index page after the delete. For whatever reason, I put a remote: true in this one and then didn't put in any js to deal with the deleted row in html.

So now in users_controller.rb

```
 def destroy
  @user.destroy
  tflash('delete', :success, {:model=>@@model, :count=>1, :now=> true})
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to(users_url) }
    format.js {}
  end
end
```

and in users/index.html.erb

```
<tr class = '<%=cycle('dataeven', 'dataodd')%>' id = '<%= dom_id(user)%>' >     
  <td class = '<%=link_cell_class%>'><%= tlink_to("destroy", destroy_user_path(user), {:navigate=>false, :method=>'delete', :remote=>true, :data=>{:confirm=>tmessage( 'delete.are_you_sure', $W, {:model=>user.username}) }})%></td>
```

and in views/users/destroy.js.erb

```
$('#user_<%=@user.id %>').remove();
```

I'll change all my deletes to use ajax in this way.

Comment: Ha - just like the answer I gave you 5 days earlier.  Good job!